# Graphs embeddable into tree like simplicial 2-complexes

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs, simplicial-complex

A [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) gives rise to a simplicial 1-complex. A tree like [simplicial 2-complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) would be simplicial 2-complex without any closed 2-subcomplexes (the analog of a cycle in graphs) and such that the 1-skeleton given by the subcomplex where more then 2 cells meet has no cycles (forms a tree).

I wonder how to prove that the following graph (of the [free modular lattice on 3 generators](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2015/09/the_free_modular_lattice_on_3.html)) cannot be embedded into such a simplicial 2-complex.

[image]

Has this generalization of planar graphs been characterized? Does it have an excluded minor characterization at all?

Comment: You have not defined what you mean by a "closed 2-subcomplex", so your question does not fully make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it can be embedded. Consider a 2-complex obtained by adding the 
edge in the middle and then the obvious 2-faces. Concretely, it means adding 3 triangles and $3\cdot3$ + $2\cdot6$ quadrilaterals. It is not acyclic yet, but after removing one quadrilateral from each cube, you get an acyclic one. Now you may subdivide the remaining quadrilaterals in order to obtain a simplicial complex.

Note: I interpret your last condition that in your 1-skeleton you consider the edges which are in more than two 2-cells. (That is, a triangulation of a plane would be OK except finiteness.)